# How to use bootstrap-date picker in angular2 rc7

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Please let me know detail configuration step by step for use bootstrap-date picker from that link https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about angular ui bootstrap date picker, but you can use https://github.com/vlio20/ng2-date-picker. It is a highly configurable date-picker.